# why can't i call one method from another inside an object

Tags: javascript

pardon my javascript ignorance: Why can't i do something like this in javascript? Running this tells me that theCalled is not defined. the order of the functions doesn't matter of course.

```js
var myObj = {
  theCaller: function() {
     console.log('The Caller');
     theCalled();
  },

  theCalled: function() {
     console.log("i was called");
  }
}

myObj.theCaller();
```

Comment: use this.theCalled()

Comment: thanks dandavis. is this because javascript doesn't have block scope? also, would this be an acceptable way of,  say, building an object, or am i using OO thinking when javascript has a different way of doing the same?

Answer (score 1):

Add "this" before you call .theCalled()

```js
var myObj = {
  theCaller: function() {
     alert('The Caller');
     this.theCalled();
  },
  theCalled: function() {
     alert("i was called");
  }
}

myObj.theCaller();
```